# Looking for database synchronisation tool

Tags: file-synchronization

I have an application called Trilium Notes by Zadam installed on a couple of my computers, which stores all the note data in a single SQLite3 database file (DB file extension). I came up with a trick to sync my notes between my two computers by replacing the directory where Trilium looks for the database by a link that points to a copy of it on my Dropbox. Therefore, every time the file is modified by Trilium on one computer, it is updated on the other.

Here's my problem: Dropbox isn't happy with two instances modifying a file at the same time, because that results in one of the two copies having to be discarded. Therefore, it takes the copy that was closed first (as far as I know) and puts it aside, marking it as "corrupt". This makes sense, except in my case where I might be modifying two different notes on separate computers, both of which belong to the same database. The specific problem here is that Dropbox treats the database as a single file like any other, rather than considering the fact that parts of it might be changed simultaneously.

Because Dropbox doesn't seem to have a feature for syncing databases in such a way, what other free cloud storage provider does, that has a working client for Linux? Would Mega work, for example?

As long as it works on Linux, I'll take that, but I'd definitely be even happier with an open source solution. I don't mind spending some time doing geeky configurations, because that would solve such an annoying problem for me. The fact is that I keep on losing the modifications I make to my notes if I'm not cautious enough to close Trilium on one computer before using it on the other all the time.

P.S. Yes, Trilium has a sync feature, but it's self-hosted, so no go for me. The advantage with a service similar to Dropbox is that it's hosted on a commercial server for free.

Comment: For syncing databases on data level you usually need knowledge on the data structures used by the application, because otherwise you don't know how to merge the data.

Comment: @Robert Interesting. So then I assume that knowing the format of the database is actually not enough. I hadn't thought of that. I'll look into Trilium's documentation and see whether I can find how it appends data to its database, in order to specify my question. Thank you for your input.

Comment: How about a local smb/samba file share storing the db on the file share.